# Accessing GUI components in thread on android

Tags: android

I want to access the component of GUI such as to change the textview from the thread
 how it can be done???

Answer (score 2):

Use a handler to send messages to the UI thread as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

It's the same as a Java `Thread` with specialization for the Android environment, and created exactly for GUI updating purpose.

From the doc:

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Comment: It is deprecated. Can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

just write it in

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread((new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textview.setText("New text");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following methods:

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
View.post(Runnable)
View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
Handler
```

More on this here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html